# Not able to add an entity as a List to a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Currently I've created a ViewModel and I was initially going to just list a "Status" as a string but now I've decided to make it into a DropDownList. I have these CallStatus as entity object. So, I figured I could just create a list of type "CallStatus" and then when I'm creating my ViewModel just call the db.CallStatus.ToList() to populate it. I would then use that list to create my DropDownList. However, I get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to CPPCallStatus.Models.CallStatus"

Here is my VM. I added the CallStautsTypes at the bottom and that's what I'm trying to populate.

```
public class CustomerCallVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Call Date")]
    public DateTime? CallDate { get; set; }

    public int? Status { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string StatusName { get; set; }

    public int? AssignedTo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Assigned To")]
    public string AssignedToName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Create Date")]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }


    public CallStatus CallStatusTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Repo where I populate the VM. I know I will need to remove the .include in the Lambda but I don't think that's the issue at the moment.

```
public CustomerCallVM SelectById(int? id)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;      

        CustomerCallVM customerCall = new CustomerCallVM();

        var call = db.CustomerCalls.Include(s => s.CallStatus).Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (call != null)
        {
            customerCall.Id = call.Id;
            customerCall.CustomerName = call.CustomerName;
            customerCall.Subject = call.Subject;
            customerCall.Comment = call.Comment;
            customerCall.CallDate = call.CallDate;
            customerCall.Status = call.Status;
            customerCall.AssignedTo = call.AssignedTo;

            customerCall.StatusName = call.CallStatus.StatusName;

            customerCall.CallStatusTypes = db.CallStatus.ToList();
        }

    return customerCall;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
public CallStatus CallStatusTypes { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<CallStatus> CallStatusTypes { get; set; }
```

Like the message says, you're trying to convert `List<CallStatus>` to `CallStatus` here: `customerCall.CallStatusTypes = db.CallStatus.ToList();`

Comment: Easy enough....should've figured that one on my own but sometimes you look at stuff to long and miss what should be obvious. Thanks!